# Selecting all columns using information_schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('`', column_name, '`'), ',')  
                                     FROM [information_schema].[columns] 
                                     WHERE table_name = 'Example') 
                       ORDER BY id) AS row_count 
FROM 
    [Example];
```

What it should do is basically partition by all columns. I'm trying to do so to count the number of duplicates for each row. In this query, instead, it just gives me the row id of each row. For example:

```
NAME   AGE   row_count
----------------------
John    12     1
Jerry   13     2
Helen   15     3
John    12     4
```

When it should be:

```
NAME   AGE   row_count
----------------------
John    12     1
Jerry   13     1
Helen   15     1
John    12     2
```

How can I fix this so that I can get a dynamic query?

Comment: That isn't going to `PARTITION BY` each column, it's going to `PARTITION BY` a **literal string** that contains the name of every column. Unsurprising, therefore, the value will be the same for every row. Use subquery you have to get the columns you need to partition on, and then paste that into your `PARTITION BY` clause instead.

Comment: @Larnu I'm trying to do this dynamically so that I don't have to manually paste

Comment: Then you'll need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Larnu How would I go about doing this in this example?

Comment: By taking the above query you have, but you would be injecting the literal string you are currently partitioning on.

Comment: @Larnu I'm a bit of a beginner, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Honestly, if you're a beginner, dynamic SQL is not a path you should be going down yet. You should be very comfortable with SQL before you startusing dynamic SQL; it *can* be a versatile tool, but it's also a very dangerous tool when used in untrained hands. In this case, I therefore refer you to my original comment, and instead create a static statement you can use.

Comment: @Larnu I'm familiar with SQL, but I'm trying to create a stored procedure for the first time. So basically a beginner in dynamic sql...don't know how to set everything up and learning to

Comment: Stored Procedures have nothing to do with Dynamic SQL. If you aren't familiar with Procedures (as you appear to suggest) this cements by point that it's too early for you to be using dynamic SQL. Learn to sit on the horse and not fall off, before you try to ride it while it gallops.

Comment: @user2896120 If you can provide sample data, so we can execute the query, we could help you better. But honestly, I am not able to understand well what the query must do exactly. Why it counts 2 in the last record of the expected results? Is it because name is John or because age is 12? Or both of them?

Comment: Something like this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7c271c55-53c0-450a-93a5-d18238d17ea0/find-duplicate-rows-dynamically-from-each-table-in-a-database?forum=transactsql?

Answer (score 0):

You should just list the desired columns that you want to partition by.

The `ORDER BY id` in the query in your question indicates that you actually want to partition by all columns **except** id.

It is possible to abuse the XML functionality to do this but I don't recommend it.

```
SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REPLACE((SELECT Example.* FOR XML PATH('')), CONCAT('<id>',id,'</id>'), '') ORDER BY id) AS row_count 
FROM 
(VALUES
(1, 'John ',  12 ),
(2, 'Jerry',  13 ),
(3, 'Helen',  15 ),
(4, 'John ',  12 )
) Example(id, NAME, AGE)
ORDER BY id
```

(Which returns...)

```
+----+-------+-----+-----------+
| id | NAME  | AGE | row_count |
+----+-------+-----+-----------+
|  1 | John  |  12 |         1 |
|  2 | Jerry |  13 |         1 |
|  3 | Helen |  15 |         1 |
|  4 | John  |  12 |         2 |
+----+-------+-----+-----------+
```

Comment: I'm getting a `Parse error at line: 5, column: 79: Incorrect syntax near 'FOR'.`

Comment: @user2896120 - the code I've posted works fine in SQL Server https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=62d86335310a8b229f620f3e2013d6d6 so either you are not using SQL Server or you have made an error trying to apply it to your situation. But you haven't shown the query that actually gives the error

Comment: I'm using Azure Synapse which from the documentation shows it's not supported unfortunately...